# SecItemAdd returns -50 on Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, security, xcode8, xcode9

The following code:

```
    var newItem = [String: Any]()

    newItem[kSecClass as String] = aValue
    newItem[kSecAttrService as String] = aValue
    newItem[kSecAttrAccount as String] = aValue
    newItem[kSecValueData as String] = aValue
    newItem[kSecAttrAccessible as String] = aValue

    // Add a the new item to the keychain.
    let status = SecItemAdd(newItem as CFDictionary, nil)

    if status != noErr {
        print("Error during access token save. \(status)")
    }
```

Works perfectly on Xcode 8 without returning any error, and returns `-50` error (aka. `errSecParam`) on Xcode 9.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer. I needed to add an host application for the Keychain framework to get a full context.

In my `xxxxxTests` target, I had to setup my main app in the `Host Application` menu (in the `General` tab).

Weird thing is that it wasn't necessary on Xcode 8.